# How to pass the list values as API request path

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a list called `enrollids` with below content:

```
['/path/one', '/path/two', '/path/three']
```

I need to pass the values above to perform API call and iterate through the list, my code looks like:

```
akacer = result.json()
enrollids = [enroll['location'] for enroll in akacer['enrollments']]

for ssl in akacer['enrollments']:
  data = {
    'enrollmentid': ssl['location'],
  }
  for i in enrollids:
    path= '{}/deployments'.format(i)
    headers = {
      "Accept": "application/vnd.acps.deployment.v7+json",
    }
    result = session.get(urljoin(baseurl, path), headers=headers, verify=False)
    deployments = result.json()
    print (deployments)
```

and the API call looks like below having incorrect URL format

```json
{'type': 'https://akab-2eznyq6aooxuiqkj-mrdlu75t6fnb6625.acps.net/path/error-types/client-error', 'title': 'Client Error', 'instance': 'https://akab-2eznyq6aooxuiqkj-mrdlu75t6fnb6625.acps.net/path/error-types/client-error?id=83be852959b84f68947caed2032647c0', 'detail': 'HTTP 406 Not Acceptable'}
```

the URL format should be

```
"https://akab-2eznyq6aooxuiqkj-mrdlu75t6fnb6625.acps.net/path/one/deployments"
"https://akab-2eznyq6aooxuiqkj-mrdlu75t6fnb6625.acps.net/path/two/deployments"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accept header should be

```
headers = {
      "Accept": "application/vnd.acps.deployments.v7+json",
    }
```